# Sharing R Markdown through MS Teams and SharePoint

Tags: r, sharepoint, r-markdown, microsoft-teams

I like to create html reports in R Markdown, but have problems sharing them inside my organization. Our main communication methods are MS Teams and SharePoint. But every time I share this way, I have to instruct users to download the document before opening it. Teams has an "Open in Browser" option, but this does not display the formatting correctly (it merges all tabs onto one page). The same goes for SharePoint, where the default is to open the document in this stripped-down format.

I could stop using tabs in the reports, but there could very well be other formatting issues that I haven't encountered yet. I don't want to share reports without the confidence that they will display as intended.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You can knit to PDF as well. Is these any reason it must be html?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be HTML. I like that format and have obtained good results with it - except when sharing! But if necessary, I'll experiment with PDF.